# HTTP POST request to express server from angular front end

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, http, mean-stack

I couldn't do the POST request to the api running in the same host but on another port from angular front end
Here's the code:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-addbook',
  templateUrl: './addbook.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./addbook.component.scss']
})
export class AddbookComponent implements OnInit {
  addForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private http:HttpClient) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.addForm=this.formBuilder.group({
      title: ['', Validators.required],
      description:['', Validators.required],
      genre: ['', Validators.required],
      author: ['', Validators.required],
      publisher: ['', Validators.required],
      pages: ['', Validators.required],
      image_url: ['', Validators.required],
      buy_url: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }
  onSubmit(){
    if(this.addForm.valid){
      console.log(this.addForm.value);
      const data = this.addForm.value;
      const headers=new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json'});
      this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/api/books",headers,data).subscribe(
        res=>{
          console.log(res);
        },
        err=>{
          console.log('err:'+err);
        }
      );
    }
  }
}
```

**Result:**
Output Console:

[image: Output Console]

Output Network:

[image: Output Network]

if you see in the second picture the header was changed to OPTIONS instead of post

http://localhost:3000/api/books - post api and
http://localhost:4200 - front-end angular

what am i missing??

Comment: The sequence of the payload `data` and `headers` is flipped in your case. Have a look at my answer to know more.

Comment: Did you read the messages in the console? You need to read up on CORS and update your backend (or add a proxy, whichever comes closer to your actual deployment configuration) accordingly.

Comment: You'll have to enable CORS on your Express Server It seems. I've added an updated answer. Please check if that helps.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I'll keep that in mind. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a look at [**`HttpClient`**](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient), it's [**`post`**](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post) method has a signature of:

```
post(
  url: string, 
  body: any, 
  options: { 
    headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; 
    observe?: HttpObserve; 
    params... = {}
): Observable<any>
```

So this:

```
this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/api/books", headers, data)...
```

should be:

```
this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/api/books", data, { headers })...
```

Payload Data(`body`) is the Second Argument to the `post` method and then comes `options` which contain things like `headers`

**ALSO:**

Looking into your console warnings looks like your Express Server is blocking requests due to the CORS Policy.

You'll also have to enable CORS on your express server. Here's how

Install CORS:

```
npm install cors --save
```

Then in your Express Server:

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())

app.get('/products/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!'})
})

app.listen(80, function () {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80')
})
```

**NOTE:** This is just a sample implementation and might change according to your implementation.

Comment: SiddAjmera, our answer is correct. I got downvote too. added you upvote

Comment: Thanks sir you just saved my head from breaking and i didn't do the vote until now sir. thanks for your help

Comment: @freepowder, actually we had missed out on a key thing. The console error presented a CORS Policy issue. So CORS had to be implemented on the OPs express server. That's what we missed and hence were downvoted. What I didn't understand is why my second answer was downvoted. It's a general courtesy to tell why someone downvotes.

Comment: @SiddAjmera the CORS was another issue on the top of bad signature of post method.  As I said in other comment, your answer was right (so as mine). And the downvote comes from people which dont provide any tech solution, just look around trying to act as if they know something about it.